# foreach and array maps error

Tags: php

I'm getting:
3 warnings (Illegal offset type in isset or empty in...)
3 notice (Undefined index: ...)

The 3 warnings are realated with the first foreach.
And the 3 notices are related with the second foreach loop.

I don't really get what I'm doing wrong...
Need some help out here.

```
<form name="form" action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['name'])) { echo $_POST['name']; } ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="age" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['age'])) { echo $_POST['age']; } ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) { echo $_POST['email']; } ?>" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
$expected = array(
    'name' => array("filter" => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
    'age' => array("filter" => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),
    'email' => array("filter" => FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)
);

foreach ($expected AS $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$value])) {
        echo "not set";
    } elseif (empty($_POST[$value])) {
        echo "empty";
    }
}

$result = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $expected);

foreach ($result AS $key => $value) {
    if (!$result[$value]) {
        echo "not valid value";
    }
}
?>
```

Thank you all.

Comment: What’s the wrong result, and what did you expect?

Comment: In the `foreach`, why do you expect `$key` to be both a value and a key?

Comment: I expect to loop through the array in the first foreach and verify if $_POST indexes are empty/null before assign values to $expected array indexes... if success I want to assing values and verify if are valid.

Comment: `$_POST[$value]` and `$result[$value]` are *key* lookups, but you are looking for a key with a value of `$value` when what you probably want is `$_POST[$key]`.

Comment: I know I've updated my code anyway, I can't get it to work! I guess what you meen is: foreach($expected AS $key){ if (!isset($_POST($key)))...

Comment: I guess the problem is related somehow with the filter introduced in the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The forms of [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) are  `foreach($iterable as $value)` and `foreach($iterable as $key => $value)`. There is no `foreach ($iterable as $key)` form as with javascript's `for (key in obj)`.

Instead use `foreach ($expected as $key => $value) {` and `foreach($result as $key=>$value) { if (!$value) die(false); }`

Your complete code should be something like this:

```
$expected = array(
    'name' => array("filter" => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
    'age' => array("filter" => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),
    'email' => array("filter" => FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)
);

foreach ($expected AS $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$key])) {  // NOT $value!!!!
        echo "not set";
    } elseif (empty($_POST[$key])) {
        echo "empty";
    }
}

$result = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $expected);

foreach ($result AS $key => $value) {
    if (!$result[$key]) {  // NOT $value!!!
        echo "not valid value";
    }
}
```

If your goal is to validate input, then I advise you not make heavy use of the PHP sanitize mechanism. Like all PHP, it is founded on the fundamentally broken philosophy of *sanitizing* input rather than *validating* it. I'm not sure what else to advise you to use, however. [Respect/Validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation) looks promising, although I think you would be better off leaving PHP if you can.

Making do with what we have, use the following function with only `FILTER_VALIDATE_*` filters. You will still need to do pre- and post-processing, and you have to emulate "chained" filters with multiple calls.

```
function filter_array($data, $filter) {
    $missing = array_diff_key($filter, $data);
    $filtered = filter_var_array($data, $filter);
    $invalid = array_filter($filtered, function($v){return $v===FALSE;});
    $filtered = array_diff_key($filtered, $missing, $invalid);
    return array($filtered, array_keys($invalid), array_keys($missing));
}
```

Example in use:

```
$_POST = array('extra'=>'extra', 'age'=>array('30a'), 'name'=>'the name');

$expected = array(
    'name'   => array("filter" => FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, // using this as a "passthrough" filter
                      "flags"  => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR, // just to set this flag
    ),
    'age'   => array("filter"  => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                     "flags"   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                     "options" => array('min_range'=>0, 'max_range'=>120)
    ),
    'email' => array("filter"  => FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL,
                     "flags"   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
    ),
);

list($valid, $invalid, $missing) = filter_array($_POST, $expected);

var_export($valid); var_export($invalid); var_export($missing);
```

Comment: I understand but not working either, I've updated my code for something more readable, thank you.

Comment: You are still confused about keys and values. I have updated my answer with the complete corrected code, although I would not do this the way you have done it. If you want to wait a while, I'll update the answer with how I would do this.

Comment: Ok, I understand that it might not be the best way to do it. And I'm confused about foreach $key and $value... :D

Comment: Now I understand what I was doing wrong!
You're so right... the value of the array index is always assign to the first variable in the foreach condition unless $array AS $key => $value then i get a proper index. Not like $array AS $key in this example $key will allways store the index $value

Comment: Thank you very much for your great example.
Can you give me a good reason to leave PHP?

Comment: http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/  A good reason *not* to leave it is you get paid to write it. (That's my reason.)

Comment: Nice article :D, Well PHP is free and fast enough isn't it? I use PHP mostly for web projects under lampp not a problem finding a server for a very low price... but I guess you're right about PHP I thought about that I used to code in AS3 and JAVA, as C++ as well I miss data types :(